# Create batch file to make a folder with the date as the name and move files into the new folder

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that creates a folder with today's date, and then copies three files into that folder. I have pieced this together from googling different solutions, but I have reached the limits of my understanding. As written, the file creates the folder and will copy the files if I replace the ????? with a folder, but I don't know how to reference the folder I created previously. I looked for solutions but honestly I didn't find any that I was able to implement successfully. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") do mkdir c:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\databasebackups\%%e-%%f-%%g
move C:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\anyfile1.db C:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\databasebackups\???????
move C:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\anyfile2.db C:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\databasebackups\???????
move C:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\anyfile3.db C:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\databasebackups\???????
```

Comment: please type `echo %date%` in a console window and provide the content returned.

Comment: That command comes back Tue 08/30/2016

Answer (score 0):

just use variables...:

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%d in ("%date%") (
    SET DayMonth=%%e
    SET MonthDay=%%f
    SET Year=%%g
)
```

and then use these variables to create directory and copy files

Answer (score 0):

This should help you along

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal
Set "parentPath=C:\Users\HP-ALT\Desktop\databasebackups"
Set "Today=%Date~-10%"
Set "newDirName=%Today:/=-%"
If Not Exist "%parentPath%\%newDirName%\" (
    MD "%parentPath%\%newDirName%"2>Nul||Exit/B)
Move…
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use the WMIC utility to extract the year, month and date information because the %date% returns the current date formatted with the Windows short format date as defined the regional settings, you can be in trouble if the current installation sets the short date format to something different than YYYY-MM-DD.

```
    @echo off
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC ^Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
        IF %%A GTR 0 (
        SET Day=%%A
        SET Hour=%%B
        SET Min=%%C
        SET Month=%%D
        SET Sec=%%E
        SET Year=%%F
        )
    )
    if %Month% LSS 10 set Month=0%Month%
    if %Day% LSS 10 set Day=0%Day%
    if %Min% LSS 10 set Minute=0%Minute%
    if %Hour% LSS 10 set Hour=0%Hour%

    set now=%year%-%month%-%day%_%hour%-%min%-%sec%
    set now=%now%
    mkdir %now%
```